# How to make a layout stay on top of the soft keyboard

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

I have an app that has a layout with a textview in it. now, what happens when using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is that the whole screen goes up when the keyboard opens. but the view is cut in half. thats an image with no keyboard:
[image]

thats with the keyboard open:
[image]

as you can see, the textbox is cut. I want it to be like facebook:
with keyboard off:
[image]

with keyboard on:
[image]

How can i menage that?  in Facebook the whole layout is above the keyboard.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout as your root layout and use

> android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

to your child view to make it slide up with the soft keyboard

Following is a sample code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    <Button
        android:text="Add Contact"
        android:id="@+id/addContact"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_below="@id/addContact"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:hint="Search" />
    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_below="@id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selection_layout"
        android:id="@+id/contactList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        ></ExpandableListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selection_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:text="Ok" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the layout is about 250 lines... i cant paste it here... but i just wanted to add that its not the last view in the scrollview layout, so cant really put android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Comment: then add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your scroll view.

Comment: tried that, acted the same.  the textbox is jumping up, but not enough. the keyboard still cutting it.

Comment: well, that works for me all the time.. I'll try and let you know soon.